# Help promote this site for Drupal's module recommendations?

Tags: discussion, advertising

There is a question on [meta.drupal.SE](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/), which is similar to the "[Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2660/13032)" question on this site here.

[Here is one of the answers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/community-promotion-ads-2017/3614#3614) over there (disclosure: it's mine), to recommend [softwarerecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for ***Recommendations*** related to "Contributed modules for Drupal". For those who want (and are able) to consider doing so, please help me "push" it over there.

And for those of you who are less familiar with [drupal.SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), be aware of this:

- Questions like "***Is there a (contributed) module to do X?***" are considered off topic over there ... most of them get put on hold right away.
- Even though "***There is a (contributed) module for it***" is like a trademarked phrase in Drupal-space, and a perfectly acceptable answer to mostly any question over there ... go figure.

To get an idea of the challenge for finding an appropriate contributed module for Drupal:

- [here is the list](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module) of ***modules*** to pick from ... right now 36,597 hits ... only.
- [here is the list](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_theme) of ***themes*** with a similar challenge ... right now 2,413 hits ... only.

More info: [Is asking for Drupal modules and/or themes on topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2444/13032)

PS: I'm not a graphics expert (can you tell?). So anybody who wants to contribute a more shiny image (which fits the dimension criteria), please let me know (eg by posting it as an answer to this meta question here).

Comment: Happen to have the source of your ad?

Comment: Not really, sorry. How about you create a brand new one that you like? More or less with the same "msg" (text) on it? Or maybe even a better one.

Comment: No worries, I might take a stab at it. Yours isn't bad at all, though. I rather like it.

Comment: Hey @Undo , how do you like my updated version (as shown in my answer here also now)?

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern ... as of today it happened ... My [Community Ad for SoftwareRecs.SE.com](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3614/39516) is now showing up on Drupal.SE. Not sure how "shiny" it is (I'm not a graphics expert ...), but this is how it looks like right now:

[image]

Anybody interested in using it to create other variation of it: go ahead, with no credits due ...

PS 1: Merci to those who voted for it also!

PS 2: There is now also a request on meta.drupal.SE to "[Add Software Recommendations as migration path](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3631/39516)"